# How to make material ui dialog show in the first half of screen height?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Dialog component from MUI which works all well.

I want to modify the existing behaviour so that the dialog is not positioned at the center of the vertical axis, rather to be position app. 30% from the top.

Current situation:

```
 | 

 |

DIALOG

 |

 |
```

Goal:

```
 | 
DIALOG
 |

 |

 |
```

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of the current DOM and a snippet of code please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to modify the css attributes of `.MuiDialog-paper` by creating a new class and assigning it to the `Dialog` component using `classes`. [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-w8829?file=/demo.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, Dialog } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  newPosOfDialog: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: "30%",
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  }
});


function Example() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Dialog
      classes={{
        paper: classes.newPosOfDialog
      }}

      /* rest of the props */
    >
       ........ 
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```